# How do I use LINQ to compare one value from its previous value?

Tags: c#, .net, linq, list

Heres the following code:

```
        Dictionary<int, List<int>> dic = new Dictionary<int, List<int>>();
        dic.Add(1, new List<int>());
        dic[1].Add(10);
        dic[1].Add(6);
        dic.Add(2, new List<int>());
        dic[2].Add(9);
        dic[2].Add(7);
        dic[2].Add(7);
        dic.Add(3, new List<int>());
        dic[3].Add(9);
        dic[3].Add(10);
        dic[3].Add(9);
        dic.Add(4, new List<int>());
        dic[4].Add(6);

        // Will give KVPs of Key 1 and 4
        var under7 = dic.Where(T => T.Value.Any(Y => Y < 7));
```

So I've easily found which KVPs contain a value of under 7.

My question is how can I iterate over the dictionary to find out KVPs which have duplicate values with a key following another key (already in order).

As in this should be picked up:

```
        dic.Add(2, new List<int>());
        dic[2].Add(9);
        dic[2].Add(7); // MATCH
        dic[2].Add(7); // MATCH
```

But not this:

```
        dic.Add(3, new List<int>());
        dic[3].Add(9); // NOT MATCH
        dic[3].Add(10);
        dic[3].Add(9); // NOT MATCH
```

Is there any way to do this using LINQ?

Tried to give it a go, using something like below but obviously it doesn't work that way.

```
        // Should give KVP of Key 2 but not 3
        var dupVals = dic.Where(T => T.Value.Aggregate( (i1, i2) => i1 == i2));
        var dupVals = dic.Where(T => T.Value.Any( (i1,i2) => i1 == i2  ));
```

EDIT:
So Sergey had the answer:

```
            var result = dic.Where(kvp =>
            kvp.Value.Skip(1).Zip(kvp.Value, (x, y) => x == y).Any(b => b));
```

But how exactly does this work?

Comment: Umm... when you run it does it not throw an out-of-bounds exception on the third line (`dic[1].Add(10);`)?

Comment: I would start with simple task - checking whether list has two consecutive duplicate values. Don't complicate question with dictionary

Comment: I feel like this would be easier with a simple `for` or `foreach` loop.

Comment: Side note: `Dictionary` *formally speaking* does not have concept of "following" as it is unordered structure.

Answer (score 7):

You can check whether list has two consecutive duplicates with

```
list.Skip(1).Zip(list, (x,y) => x == y).Any(b => b)
```

Do this for each value in dictionary:

```
// yep, you can use this pretty initializer
var dic = new Dictionary<int, List<int>> {
    { 1, new List<int> { 10, 6 }},
    { 2, new List<int> { 9, 7, 7 }},
    { 3, new List<int> { 9, 10, 9 }},
    { 4, new List<int> { 6 }}
};

var result = dic.Where(kvp =>
       kvp.Value.Skip(1).Zip(kvp.Value, (x, y) => x == y).Any(b => b));
```

Explanation: [`Enumerable.Zip`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/dd267698(v=vs.100).aspx) extension applies specified function `(x,y) => x == y` to corresponding elements of two sequences. These two sequences is list, and same list shifted one item forward. I.e. you are applying function to `index` and `index + 1` items of same list. This function produces result of items comparison. So, Zip will return sequence of `true` and `false` depending on equality of consecutive items. If there is any `true` in result, then you have two consecutive duplicates.

Step by step sample: Consider following list `9, 10, 9, 7, 7`. If you'll skip first item in this list, you will get sequence `10, 9, 7, 7`. Zipping of these two sequences will produce following item pairs (you should pic corresponding items - first and first, second and second, etc): `(10, 9), (9, 10), (7,9), (7,7)`. Next step is applying `(x,y) => x == y` function to each pair. Result will be `false, false, false, true`. As you can see, last pair (fourth item from first sequence and fourth item from second sequence) has equal items, thus it produces `true`. And last thing is checking whether any of pairs produced `true`.

Comment: The `Zip` extension method is one of the most under-used extension methods of the Linq family.  As such, a tiny bit of explanation would go a long way for future visitors.  Otherwise, it's a great answer.

Comment: +1 you can can call Any with no argument in this case

Comment: @BlackBear No you can't. With no argument it will verify if the sequence is not empty, not whether it contains any value that is `true`.

Comment: @BartoszKP that's right, this means it's too late and I should go to bed :p

Comment: @BlackBear I'll delete my comments, not to make unnecessary noise :)

Comment: God damm thats amazing!
But how does it exactly work? Could you break down the individual LINQ steps?

Comment: @JimmyTo sorry, I need to go now. But no problem - I'll add more detailed explanation today